# Unable to Import in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

I'm new to python and I've been using VS code. Right now I'm working on a Thompson Sampling problem that requires numpy and matplotlib. I've imported both libraries but VS code is giving the error unable to import. I know I have to install with PIP, and I have seen other solutions about changing the Python path through the json. but I'm afraid to do that because I don't want to mess up my text editor. Can someone walk me through what I am supposed to do? I haven't seen any simple tutorials on setting up VS Code for python. I'm hoping this will help other people too! I have the extensions Python and CodeRunner installed in VS code. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**solution to this is make virtual environment for your project steps are as follows**
    1.go to specifid directory you want to make project.
    2.open cmd or teminal an type `mkdir testProjectName`.
    3.type `cd testProjectName`.
    4.type `virtualenv venv`.
    5.type for windows `source venv/scripts/activate`
      type for linux or mac `source venv/bin/activate`
    6.type `pip install python`.
    7.type `pip install numpy`.
    8.type `pip install matplotlib`.
    9.make your project 'testProjectName' dir or copy and paste you project here.
Hope this helps.....

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3, the issue is most likely that when you installed numpy and matplotlib you used the `pip` command, which will only install them for Python 2. To install the libraries for Python 3 just use the `pip3` command in place of `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me when installing numpy but after i restarted VScode it fixed it's self.
if that didn't work check that the package is installed with: pip list in the command prompt.