# ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL working with keras in VSCode

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, visual-studio-code, importerror

I've created a REST API with node.js then python script is called by python-shell, everything was fine so far. I want to decode base64 to image and send model. But I am getting an error even if pillow already installed. I am using windows 10 and python 3.7.4

```py
File "..\ml.py", line 19, in <module> img = image.load_img(file,target_size=(224,224))
File "C:..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 111, in load_img
raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image.')
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from keras.models import load_model
import base64

def decode(str):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str)
    filename = 'some_image.jpg'  
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
    return filename


str = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
  str = str + line 
file = decode(str)

img = image.load_img(file,target_size=(224,224))
img = np.asarray(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

saved_model = load_model("model.h5")
output = saved_model.predict(img)
```

Comment: I did not create virtual enviroment for vscode. I've created virtual enviroment then activate virtual enviroment. It works now! You can check for more information [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272258/unable-to-import-in-vs-code)  & [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)